# Custom Menu for Mac Catalyst App in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, mac-catalyst

Can anyone help with an example on how to configure the menu for a Mac Catalyst app in Objective-C? The main intent is to get rid of most of the menu items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your Main.storyboard for your project. Near the upper right hand corner, there is a `+` button to add objects from library, click that button and search for Main Menu then add it to your Main.storyboard. From there you should be able to select items and delete the unwanted ones. I believe you won't be able to remove the Application menu.